# Android tab with navigation

Tags: android

Hi there can you guys help me with my problem with my listview with navigation. Ughh, Because I cant make my normal page with tabs add a navigation drawer, here is my messed up code thanks guys. This code is working but my fab buttons are missing in the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#990000"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                android:background="#990000">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/car"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use fab button as child of CoordinateLayout not the child of LinearLayout and should use toolbar as child of appbarlayout

note : AppbarLayout is custom linearlayout

CoordinateLayout is custom framelayout

use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.OwnerTabs">



        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            android:background="#990000">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#990000"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_create_black_24px"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_white_24px"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/container"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    />
```